# I have python script which included some bash commands in os.system(). Will this work in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, bash, pyinstaller, pdftk

I have a python script which included some bash commands in os.system() method .
If I convert this python script to exe using Pyinstaller,  will this exe file work properly in windows OS or will I face any issues since Windows can't run bash commands ?

the bash commands include pdftk utility.
 Example : pdftk input_pdf output output_pdf userpw password

Should I install pdftk utility also in Windows.

What should I do or install to make it work in Windows ?
Please help me..
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It won't work, os.system is os specific, in Windows it will just spawn a cmd process and try to execute that command and cmd != bash.

Edit: powershell has a lot of common bash commands implemented on windows, you could try to figure out in the code what os are you running on and if powershell supports your bash commands you could use the subprocess module to spawn powershell processes

Comment: can I use other methods like subprocess.Popen() or subprocess.call() to run bash commands  in Windows

Answer (score 0):

It probably will not work, from what I have seen when using bash commands inside of code on windows.

Solutions:

1. Change the commands to commands that work on Windows.
2. Use some kind of python api (if you know of one post it in the comments and I will put it here.) that allows you to use the commands you need.
3. Simply run the script using the bash terminal on windows, but you won't be able to make it a exe as far as I know.

Comment: I think even though you use one of bash simulator in windows, a lot of bash commands cannot run correctly. Especially commands related to path.

Comment: I don't actually know how well the bash terminal that they added to windows 10 works, I haven't actually tried it because I have a mac laptop that I do the most of my development on so I have no need to use it. I just knew of it and thought it might be a solution to this persons issue.

Comment: bash is a shell, not a terminal. There are existing ports to Windows, Cygwin, and MSYS that are popular, especially the latter (e.g. git-bash). Windows 10 has updated the built-in console to support a virtual terminal interface. This is required for the new Linux subsystem (WSL), which runs native Linux binaries by using a kernel pico process driver that implements Linux system calls. This provides a full Linux command-line environment (but not X Window GUI) for a supported distro such as Ubuntu. With WSL we're running native Linux bash instead of a port.